# converting data frame to time series in R unemployment

Tags: r, time-series

I downloaded the unemployment data from 1980-2017 from the Bureau of Labor Statistics. I uploaded the file to R and tried to convert it to time series with as.ts(unemployment) but I'm not getting an appropriate graph. I have 13 columns, with the 1st column representing the Years with values from 1980-2017, and the other 12 columns representing the months and the values of unemployment. Ex:

as.ts(unemployment)

Time Series:

Start = 1

End = 38

Frequency = 1

Years  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun Jul Aug  Sep  Oct

1  1980  6.3  6.3  6.3  6.9  7.5  7.6 7.8 7.7  7.5  7.5

2  1981  7.5  7.4  7.4  7.2  7.5  7.5 7.2 7.4  7.6  7.9

3  1982  8.6  8.9  9.0  9.3  9.4  9.6 9.8 9.8 10.1 10.4

November and december were suppressed because of space

Comment: Please consider some code example and output of what you currently get. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Note that columns in your dataframe represents different things (mixing variables and observations) with different meanings. For example first column is `year`, whereas others are `months`. Therefore you have to `tidy` your dataframe first. Using example data above:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_ts <- df %>% 
  gather(key=Month, value=Value, -Year) %>% 
  mutate(Month=factor(Month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
                                        "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                                        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
                                        "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))) %>% 
  arrange(Year, Month) %>% 
  pull(Value) %>% 
  as.ts(start=c(1980,1), end=c(2017,12), frequency=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either go the `tidyverse` way using `tidyr::gather()` or coerce your dataframe to matrix before converting it to `ts` object.

I will let someone else elaborate on how to melt a dataframe, here's a suggestion of the second, base R approach.

Your data:

```
set.seed(12)
dfm <- matrix(round(rnorm(38*12), digits = 2),
                                 nrow = 38, ncol = 12)
colnames(dfm) <- month.abb
df<- data.frame(Year=seq(1980, 2017), dfm)
```

First I suggest you remove `Year` variable and put it into the row names:

```
rownames(df)<-df$Year
df$Year <- NULL

#head(df)
```

Then you can coerce your dataframe to matrix. Watch out for direction of the matrix - you will have to transpose it before interpreting it as vector.

```
df_ts <- ts(as.vector(t(as.matrix(df))), 
   start=c(1980,1), end=c(2017,12), frequency=12)
```

Now you have your `ts` object which you can plot:

```
plot(df_ts)
```

[image: ts]